# Sending UTF-8 keycodes instead of UTF-16 in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, synergy, utf-8

To my understanding, Windows 10 sends the keypress to the programs in UTF-16 since a while back. While I like the idea it poses a *huge* problem for me as I have software ([Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/)) that doesn’t support it.

So I wonder if there is some way to for Windows to send “normal” UTF-8 keycodes?

Here is the known problem for the Barrier software [described here](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/217).

Barrier:
UTF-8 tickbox didn't help for me even if it was suggested on multiple places.
The solution I finally found that worked was to switch the client language to my native language. This work even as I have since moved on to Linux on the server.

Comment: Doesn't this work for you? https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/217#issuecomment-560354964 (straight from your link)

Comment: A _keypress_ has nothing to do with Unicode. A keypress event could be _key X down_ or _key Y pressed together with Alt_ or _key Z released_. This  information can be encoded somehow, but Unicode does not have any concept for key press, key release, or stringing several keys together.

Answer (score 3):

Native 'Unicode' programs in Windows **always** deal with UTF-16. This is not new to Win10 – it has been the case in Win7, WinXP, Win2000, the whole Windows NT series.

However, to retain compatibility with very old (Win98-era) software, Windows has a dual API – practically every function which works with strings has two versions behind the scenes, an 'Unicode' version such as CreateFileW() which uses UTF-16, and an 'ANSI' version such as CreateFileA() which uses legacy Windows-125x charsets. The programmer simply writes "CreateFile()" and it's replaced with one or the other when compiling.

But many programmers who write cross-OS software find UTF-16 quite inconvenient, as it cannot be handled in simple C strings. So recently Microsoft decided they could finally repurpose the Win98 compatibility APIs and added [this checkbox](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16695786/69955737-a6265480-14fe-11ea-81f4-80b6e5f2461a.PNG) which switches the 'ANSI' functions to use UTF-8 instead of Windows-125x. However, this does nothing to the 'Unicode' functions which remain UTF-16 as before.

So the problem isn't that Windows switched from UTF-8 to UTF-16; that has never been the case. The problem – if the GitHub thread is correct – is that the program in question appears to be compiled to use the 'ANSI' APIs (which had never been Unicode-compatible *at all* in the past), and Windows switched *those* from CP1252 *to* UTF-8.

To fix it – as the user "AZeroEight" writes:

> There is a checkbox for Beta UTF-8 support which was checked on the new system - unchecking and restarting Barrier solved the issue for me.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution provided by AZeroEight don't work for me for some reason. Both system had the checkbox unchecked as default, I have even checked them, saved and then uncheck them again and save just to be sure.
But thanks for a very good explanation  on what is going on as well as a possible solution (manual compilation with setting, just need to figure out on how to do it).